# slick slider, different css for multiple sliders on one page

Tags: jquery

I'm using "slick" (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for more than one slider on the same page. Now i'd like to set different css-styles for each slider so that i can change the style of the arrows for each slider. I didn't find anything on google. Has anybody an idea how i can do that?

thanks for help, regards
thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap each slider inside a div with its own id (`id="slider-1"`, `id="slider-2"`, etc),
then create multiple css rules:

```
// first slider
#slider-1 button.slick-prev {
   ...
}
#slider-1 button.slick-next {
   ...
}

// second slider
#slider-2 button.slick-prev {
   ...
}
#slider-2 button.slick-next {
   ...
}

/* etc.*/
```